# Can this container withstand a vacuum?

Tags: pressure, vacuum

I am putting together a piece of equipment that will involve a vacuum pump pulling up to 10 Torr / 13 Mbar.

I need to use a container for liquid within the equipment and have found a stainless steel keg that the manufacturer states can withstand 130 psi.

Will this keg be strong enough to withstand the vacuum?

Comment: Be careful about any engineering advice you receive online. It may not be safe advice.

Comment: @Inquisitive by the way, everything on this site comes with the implicit disclaimer that we're not responsible for property damage, injury, death, etc. resulting from following advice on this site. Actually it's even written in the ToS. It never hurts to make this disclaimer explicit, but it's not really something that needs moderator attention.

Answer (score 1):

130psi corresponds to about 9bar (about 9 times greater than 987mbar). Assuming the container has the same ability to keep air out as it does to keep it in, this would be amply strong enough.

Comment: The pressure difference is actually atmosphere - 13mbar = 9987 mbar.

Comment: You mean 987mb, but yes, that's a good point - I'll edit.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, yes, since 0.987 bar < 9bar, but you need to be careful about the direction of the force. A typical keg is designed to withstand overpressure (i.e. a force pushing on the inside). However, if you evacuate it, the pressure points in the other direction, which the keg may not be designed for.

I thoroughly recommend using a vacuum vessel that has been designed for the use.

Not in the question, but a keg will likely be very contaminated, which might affect your application.

Answer (score 1):

I will second @Eoin and say to use a vessel designed for the use.  Assumptions about strengths of vessels under pressure (tension) vs vacuum (compression) can be dangerous. The manufacturer's statement of maximum working pressure (130 psi) will be based on the ASME Boiler code (or similar codes in other countries). The 130psi would correspond to the Maximum Allowable Working Pressure.  The ASME codes also define a Minimum Allowable External Working Pressure - if your vessel is not so rated (and a keg likely isn't), than it is not rated for holding vacuum against external air pressure. The codes have various sections on requirements for dealing with external pressure, so the design standards are, in fact, different.

However! ASME codes do not apply to vessels having an internal or external pressure not exceeding 15 psi (your usage). They also do not apply to vessels having an inside diameter, width, height, or cross section diagonal not exceeding 6 inches. (So, why the ratings in the previous paragraph? Well, it lets you know if you can pump out what is nominally a pressure vessel down to vacuum to, for example, remove all process gases).

So, your usage of the keg to hold liquid inside a vacuum chamber would not violate any ASME codes, but nothing about the rating of the vessel guarantees that it would work.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. Unlike vessels under internal pressure, vessels under external pressure are vulnerable to the so-called buckling (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y5VRww1Ypwk ), so a thin shell can withstand high internal pressure, but not high external pressure.